# deploying appication, device is developer locked

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, deployment, zune

I have deployed apps before to my window phone, but today when i try to deploy my new app something go wrong

[image]

the zune is running my phone is unlocked, my windows live account is right, and when i enter the developer registration this is happening

[image]

so i spent a long time looking for solution, but i didn't find one. did anybody had the same problem? what can cause this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phone's registration automatically expires after 1 year, that's probably the problem your facing. Though I'm not sure why you can't re-register it directly using the registration tool.

To solve this issue:

1. Go on the [Windows Phone Dev Center website](https://dev.windowsphone.com/) and log-in
2. Go the [devices management page](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/Account/Devices) (click on your live id in the top right corner, then on "Phones")
3. Search your phone in the list and click on "Remove"
4. Launch the Developer Phone Registration tool to re-register your phone