# Register Windows Phone 7 as developer phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, zune

I am running win 8.1 x64 and have followed [this guide](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-fix-windows-phone-7-and-zune-devices-connection-problems-and-issues/) because I tried to resolve this message:

[image]

I have found this kb article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468307

I have also closed zune, deleted the certificates and restarted zune. which did not help
and also tried to add a copy of the certificate to the trusted ones, as listed in the kb article.

I am becoming desperate. The ipoverusbsvc is running fine. I did register a windows phone 8 device and have this error also at an other windows phone 7. So it is just my pc and windows phone 7 devices. Have tried an htc trophy and lumia 800 the lumia 920 (wp8) works fine.
The lumia 800 has an active sim in it. the trophy does not (I think) Is it required to have zune logged in (live id)?

[image]

**edit** I have read somewhere that you do not need to launch zune! When I navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x64`
and run `WpConnect.exe` it gives this message:

> Failed to connect to the device. Ensure that the device is completely booted and
>    is connected to the PC. (0x80070103)

But the phone is booted, swiped away the lockscreen... When I run `phonereg.exe` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Phone Registration` it tells me to verify that ipoverusbsrv should be up and running, which is up and running.

[image]

[image]

I also added zune to the firewall exceptions and followed these steps on the device: http://forums.wpcentral.com/developers-corner/211829-visual-studio-stopped-connecting-wp7.html

**edit 2** I tried to install win 7 in a virtual pc to test if it works on that os. But I got a message that the wp sdk 8 cannot be installed on win7. it was packaged with the visual studio 2012 express for windows phone...

Comment: Can you download any application from marketplace on that device?

Comment: yes it downloads and installs everything

Comment: You might get better answers at the http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ beta site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to run Windows 7 in a virtual machine with Zune. It does not work on Windows 8.1 with Zune. You cannot register a Windows Phone 7 with windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

The device that wanted to be registered as a developer device should be logged in with a Microsoft Live account. If you can download any application from marketplace this means that phone is logged in.

Could you try again registering your device with another usb port or another micro usb cable?

Comment: I have had a lumia 800 with the same error. that lumia has an live id configured. I also tried an other usb cable. This cable works with my lumia 920. the trophy has no live id installed. the zune client has no live id, is that the issue? Then why does the error tell me otherwise?

Comment: Have resetted the thropy. logged in with developer live id. logged in on zune with same live id. still the same error...

Comment: Okay, this is so strange. Can you check update on your phone? Im thinking about your explanations and your problem but I cant see any reason to face that problem.

Maybe it could be about SDK version? If your phone running on 7.8 OS and your computer's has 7.5 SDK, this could be the reason but as you guess im just trying to figure it out.

Comment: The phone runs 7.8 (7.10 (8862) or something) My pc has the latest sdk because app development for wp8 works fine (also deployed an app in the market) I have the latest zune. the latest sdk 8 should work for wp7.x according to the changelog. and i have the 7.8 sdk update installed. (just verified that)

Comment: Have you ever tried removing your device from Device Manager (when it's still plugged) and unplug and plug it again? Im done bro. I don't have any more advice :)

Comment: I have followed this link now. http://www.technipages.com/zune-solve-connection-error-messages-when-connecting-your-phone.html My registration app looks different then this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196317/deploying-appication-device-is-developer-locked?rq=1 really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, each SDK has different registration software and their design a little different than each other. Following page is a very older SDK, you're running 7.8 its normal, the latest one is yours. I couldn't solve your problem, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run phonereg.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows Phone**v8.0**\Tools\Phone Registration

Your problem is "v8.0". I tried on a Windows 8 (not 8.1) machine running this file -
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\Phone Registration\PhoneReg.exe

and it worked like a charm. Note the "v7.1" in the path.

> I tried to install win 7 in a virtual pc to test if it works on that
>   os. But I got a message that the wp sdk 8 cannot be installed on win7

Correct, but irrelevant. If you want to register a WP7 phone you need to use the WP7.1 SDK

Comment: It has been a while, but I believe that I downloaded the 7.8 version or that 7.8 runs with the 8.0 sdk or something. Though nice that you have it working on windows 8 with the sdk 7.1! I thought that 7.1 was outdated and that the 7.5 or 7.8 was required these days. If I would make an app today, I'd make a universal app. ps. you need to unlock your wp7.x phone before 1 jan 2015

Comment: 7.1 = 7.5, they are just different names for the same thing. One name for developers and one for consumers. 7.8 is really just cosmetics. It adds new emulator images and live tile support but no new apis. You can develop 7.1/7.5/7.8 wp apps with the wp8 sdk but you cannot developer unlock a wp7 device with the wp8 sdk because wp7 and wp8 device unlock work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but perhaps others try to register their phone in the last minute just like me:

1. Windows 8.1 Pro Update (= latest version as of today)
2. Control Panel → Program and Features → Turn Windows features on or off → .NET Framework 3.5
3. [Zune 4.8](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=27163)
4. [Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://dev.windows.com/develop/download-phone-sdk)

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Phone Registration

I registered one phone with SIM inserted, one without.
I registered one phone with Windows Live ID, one without.
I registered one phone as Zune sync guest, one as full partner.
I registered one phone with Windows Phone 7.5, one with 7.8.
Windows Phone SDK 8.1 did not work for me.
Windows Phone SDK 7.1 did not work for me, even not in Windows 7 Ultimate (not required because the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 comes with SDK 7.1 actually).
My Microsoft Account has two-step verification enabled.
Now, these phones are listed in my [Windows Phone Dev Center](https://dev.windowsphone.com/Account/Devices).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I believe that Microsoft does not allow windowsphone 7.x to be registered as developer phone after 31-dec-2014 (http://nokiaviews.com/microsoft-will-not-allow-you-to-unlock-your-wp-7-x-device-after-december-31.html)