# Trouble developer registering a Windows Phone 7 - Live ID not recognised

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-7

I have a Lumia 800 (WP 7) that used to be developer unlocked, but seems not to be anymore, so I can't deploy an app to it. OK, I tried to use the develop registering tool. It sees the phone, and then prompts me to log into App Hub with my Live ID. I understand this is the same as the Microsoft Account nowadays, but the tool says logging in does not succeed and asks to check the credentials.

At the same time I am logged in to the WP Dev Center with my Microsoft Account which works fine. So I'm confused why the developer registration tool does not let me in.

I have tried this with two computers, both running Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone, with the same result. Tried also a Windows 8.1 and WP SDK running in VS 2013, which asks to run Zune. I haven't Zune there and failed when tried to install it.

I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884127/register-windows-phone-7-as-developer-phone), which advises to use Windows 7 environment, but as explained it does not work for me. So what am I missing? Is the registration tool outdated?

Comment: Turn off firewall and antivirus and try again. Be sure that phone is connected and screen is unlocked.